natables routing decision step(s)
On the link below is an image explaining packet flow across chains in nftables
Netfilter hooks
I understanding everything except one thing, the image does not explain at which stage is routing decision done?
According to the image it should be done in 2 places:

After prerouting hook but before input and forward hood
Before output hook when a packet leaves localhost process

First point above makes sense because there are 2 possible hooks that follow prerouting, however for point 2 it's not clear what routing decision is to be performed since the only flow option from local process is the output hook so there shouldn't be any routing decision but the image says there is one.
This makes me believe that there is only one routing decision which is in point 1 above.
Why does the image specify routing decision node between local process and output hook?
SNAT is done in postrouting hook which according to docs "sees all packets after routing, just before they leave the local system"
But the question is which routing? since there are 2 routing decisions according to the image.
And btw. what is "routing decision" (node in the image) I don't think that's NAT because NAT is done in prerouting and postrouting hooks.

The image is right.
The routing is done only once: since Local Process is a starting point or termination point, a packet flow go through only one routing decision.
For your second point, the flow will go through:

local process
routing decision
output
postrouting
egress
driver tx

There is nothing prior to this, so it will only go through one routing decision.
In this case, routing decision means chosing to which IP address, using which interface, you will send your packet.
If I want to send a packet to 1.1.1.1, it would mean doing:
$ ip r get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 src 192.168.1.254 uid 1000 
    cache 

So I will send my packet (srcip:192.168.1.254, dstip:1.1.1.1) to 192.168.1.1 on my Wi-Fi interface wlp0s20f3.
Once I chosed this, I could change the ip header source ip if I want to do snat.

You said There is nothing prior to this, so it will only go through one routing decision. but that's exactly why the picture is wrong because there is nothing to route from local process. If routing decision means system consulting routing table then that's independent of nftables ans so the picture should mention only 1 routing decision instead of 2.

Yes, routing decision means system consulting routing table. It's independant of nftables, although it is mentionned because it's useful to know when it happens. (and for the other routing decision because you chose to go to input or forward based on this). The picture shows 2 routing decision steps, but one flow will only go through one (because a flow cannot be both input and output). Also yes, there is something to route from local process, packets generated by a local process will need to be routed to go through one interface.

I think I get it, my impression from the image was that routing decision means nftables deciding whether to forward packets or directing to local process, and since output connection don't go to forward chain but only to postrouting that appeared as if no routing happens output.

Btw. I have found yet another picture which confirms consistency and your point that "routing decision" means consulting routing table. https://thermalcircle.de/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=linux:nf-ct-iptables-hooks-ipv4.png
